# Gatsby Markdown Text: In develop mode, I see the markdown text is shown as empty during hot reload

Tags: gatsby, hot-reload

I am working on a react front-end. I am able to pull my markdown text defined in Dato CMS and show it on my react-frontend (browser) in gatby develop mode. Being in develop mode, when I change my component slightly and click save in VS code, during hotreload of the page, the markdown text on the page shows empty. Wonder why ?

Comment: Do you see the text when you manually refresh the page (F5)?